# How to get rowIndex in an Angular Material mat-cell

Tags: angular, angular-material, row, mat-table

I have a material table that I'm trying to set a selected class on the mat-cell definition, but I need to know the row index that the mat-cell is in. Below I'm trying the row index from the matRowDef in the call to isCellSelected when trying to set the class for the mat-cell, but it's undefined. Thanks in advance.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="ds" matSort style="width: 100%;">

   

    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of gridColumns" [matColumnDef]="column">

        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ column }}</th>

        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let object; let cellIndex = index;"

            (mousedown)="onCellMouseDown($event, cellIndex)"

            (mouseup)="onCellMouseUp($event, cellIndex)"

            [class.selected]="isCellSelected(cellIndex, rowIndex)">{{ object[column] }}</td>

    </ng-container>



    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>

    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns; let rowIndex = index;"

        (click)="onRowClicked(row)"

        (mousedown)="onRowMouseDown($event, rowIndex)"

        (mouseup)="onRowMouseUp($event, rowIndex)"></tr>



</table>
```

Comment: so cellIndex will be the same as rowIndex, why do you need both?

Comment: @robbieAreBest, you would be right. After some testing I see what you say. thanks.